# Coupled oscillations - problem with real expression of general solution

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the following problem:

[image]

$$
m\ddot{x_1}=-kx_1-s(x_1-x_2)\\m\ddot{x_2}=-kx_2+s(x_1-x_2)
$$

Now, I make the ansatz
$$
x_1(t)=\alpha_1e^{i\omega t},\qquad x_2(t)=\alpha_2e^{i\omega t}.
$$
Putting this into the equations, I get
$$
\begin{pmatrix}-m\omega^2+k+s & -s\\-s & -m\omega^2+k+s\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1\\\alpha_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Setting the determinant to $0$, i.e.
$$
(-w\omega^2+k+s)^2-s^2=0,
$$
I get the two solutions
$$
\omega_+=\sqrt{\frac{k+2s}{m}},\qquad \omega_-=\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}.
$$

For $\omega_+$, we have $\alpha_1=-\alpha_2$, and for $\omega_-$, we have $\alpha_1=\alpha_2$.

So, we have the two eigenfrequences
$$
\omega_+\text{ and }\omega_-
$$
and the two eigen oscillations
$$
x_1(t)=-\alpha_2 e^{i\omega_+ t}, x_2(t)=-\alpha_1 e^{i\omega_+ t}~~(1)
$$
and
$$
x_1(t)=\alpha_1 e^{i\omega_- t}, x_2(t)=\alpha_1 e^{i\omega_- t}.~~(2)
$$

Now, in the solution I found the following:

> > The general solution is a linear combination of the two eigen oscillations. **In real form**, this is
> >     $$
> > x_1(t)=\alpha_1\cos(\omega_- t+\phi)+\alpha_1'\cos(\omega_+ t+\phi'),~~(3)\\
> > x_2(t)=\alpha_1\cos(\omega_- t+\phi)-\alpha_1'\cos(\omega_+ t+\phi'),~~(4)
> > $$
> >     where the unknown $\alpha_1,\alpha_1',\phi,\phi'$ are determined by the initial values.

How do we get this real form?

If the general solution is a linear combination of the two eigen oscillations (1) and (2), I would think this means

$$
\begin{pmatrix}x_1(t)\\x_2(t)\end{pmatrix}=a\cdot\begin{pmatrix}-\alpha_2e^{i\omega_+t}\\-\alpha_1 e^{i\omega_+ t}\end{pmatrix}+b\cdot\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1 e^{i\omega_- t}\\\alpha_1 e^{i\omega_- t}\end{pmatrix},
$$
i.e.
$$
x_1(t)=a\cdot\alpha_1e^{i\omega_+ t}+b\cdot\alpha_1e^{i\omega_- t},\\
x_2(t)=-a\cdot\alpha_1 e^{i\omega_+ t}+b\cdot\alpha_1 e^{i\omega_- t}
$$
for some coefficients $a,b$.

Setting $c:=a\alpha_1$ and $d:=b\alpha_1$, I get
$$
x_1(t)=ce^{i\omega_+ t}+de^{i\omega_- t},\\
x_2(t)=-ce^{i\omega_+ t}+d e^{i\omega_- t}.
$$

If I now use the Euler formula, I get
$$
x_1(t)=c\cdot (\cos(\omega_+ t)+i\cdot \sin(\omega_+ t))+d\cdot (\cos(\omega_- t)+i\cdot\sin(\omega_- t)),\\
x_2(t)=-c\cdot (\cos(\omega_+ t)+i\cdot \sin(\omega_+ t))+d\cdot (\cos(\omega_- t)+i\cdot\sin(\omega_- t)).
$$

Now, the **real form** just means to leave the summands $i\cdot\sin(\omega_+ t)$ and $i\cdot\sin(\omega_- t)$ away?

Comment: You shouldn't the same $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ in formulas (1)+(2) vs. (3)+(4)

Comment: Besides, have you seen that the equation which gives you the two solutions for $\omega^2$ is the characteristic equation of the matrix of the system: you are working with eigenvalues...

Comment: Yes, the $\omega_+$ and $\omega_-$ are eigenvalues.

Comment: Are there any initial conditions?

Comment: it is the squares of the $\omega_{+/-}$ that are the eigenvalues.

Comment: @JeanMarie In which sense is the equation $(-m\omega^2+k+s)^2-s^2=0$ the characteristic equation? Did not get your point.

Comment: I meant that if you put your system :$$m\ddot{x_1}=-kx_1-s(x_1-x_2)\\m\ddot{x_2}=-kx_2+s(x_1-x_2)$$ into the canonical form $X''=AX$, the matrix $A$ you get has a characteristic equation $\det(A-\lambda I_2)=0$ which is the same as the polynomial in $\omega^2$ that you have found. In a certain sense, you "rediscover" the origin of the charateristic equation, that's all.

Comment: I think you get confused by your own notation here.

In (1) you work with $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$...

Last equation should read:

$x_1(t) = a \exp(i\omega_{+} t) + b \exp(i\omega_{-} t)$

$x_2(t) = a \exp(i\omega_{+} t) - b \exp(i\omega_{-} t)$

Comment: @JeanMarie Okay, I have $$\begin{pmatrix}\ddot{x_1}\\\ddot{x_2}\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{m}\begin{pmatrix}-k-s & s\\-s & -k-s\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}$$. And what you mean is to set $\left|\frac{1}{m}\begin{pmatrix}-k-s-\lambda & s\\-s & -k-s-\lambda\end{pmatrix}\right|=0$ and to solve for $\lambda$, right? That is, if we understand the second derivative as a linear operator, we have an eigenvalue problem.

Comment: Yes, its exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

> To solve (set $s=z$ because we use $s$ for the Laplace transforms):
>
> $$
> \begin{cases}
> \text{m}x_1''(t)=-\text{k}x_1(t)-z\left(x_1(t)-x_2(t)\right)\\
> \text{m}x_2''(t)=-\text{k}x_2(t)+z\left(x_1(t)-x_2(t)\right)
> \end{cases}
> $$

---

Use Laplace transform:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{m}s^2\text{X}_1(s)-\text{m}sx_1(0)-\text{m}x_1'(0)=-\text{k}\text{X}_1(s)-z\left(\text{X}_1(s)-\text{X}_2(s)\right)\\
\text{m}s^2\text{X}_2(s)-\text{m}sx_2(0)-\text{m}x_2'(0)=-\text{k}\text{X}_2(s)+z\left(\text{X}_1(s)-\text{X}_2(s)\right)
\end{cases}
$$

So, we can use this to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{X}_1(s)\left[\text{m}s^2+\text{k}+z\right]=z\text{X}_2(s)+\text{m}sx_1(0)+\text{m}x_1'(0)\\
\text{X}_2(s)\left[\text{m}s^2+\text{k}+z\right]=z\text{X}_1(s)+\text{m}sx_2(0)+\text{m}x_2'(0)
\end{cases}
$$

Now, we get that:

- $$\text{X}_1(s)\left[\text{m}s^2+\text{k}+z\right]=z\cdot\left(\frac{z\text{X}_1(s)+\text{m}sx_2(0)+\text{m}x_2'(0)}{\text{m}s^2+\text{k}+z}\right)+\text{m}sx_1(0)+\text{m}x_1'(0)$$
- $$\text{X}_2(s)\left[\text{m}s^2+\text{k}+z\right]=z\cdot\left(\frac{z\text{X}_2(s)+\text{m}sx_1(0)+\text{m}x_1'(0)}{\text{m}s^2+\text{k}+z}\right)+\text{m}sx_2(0)+\text{m}x_2'(0)$$

Solving this gives us:

- $$\text{X}_1(s)=\frac{\text{m}\left(x_1'(0)+s\left(x_1(0)+\frac{zx_2(0)}{\text{m}s^2+\text{k}+z}\right)+\frac{zx_2'(0)}{\text{m}s^2+\text{k}+z}\right)}{\text{k}+\text{m}s^2+z-\frac{z^2}{\text{m}s^2+\text{k}+z}}$$
- $$\text{X}_2(s)=\frac{\text{m}\left(x_2'(0)+s\left(x_2(0)+\frac{zx_1(0)}{\text{m}s^2+\text{k}+z}\right)+\frac{zx_1'(0)}{\text{m}s^2+\text{k}+z}\right)}{\text{k}+\text{m}s^2+z-\frac{z^2}{\text{m}s^2+\text{k}+z}}$$